# How Can I Find Which Component Re-render

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I wonder is there any way to see component re-render stuation :)

Comment: What error? We can't help diagnose or debug code we can't see. Please share a [mcve] so we've some context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. install "React Developer Tools " extension  in your
   browser
2. step 2: inspect the code  you will have component
   section open that you will find which component gets
   error see in image

[image: see image]